# Why doesnt this grep command work

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write a grep command that will match a python function declaration, in the form

def hello(hello)

so def, one space, a word that starts with either a letter, number or an underscore, open parenthesis, another word, closed parenthesis. I'm using the command

```
grep ^"def "[/-a-zA-z0-9][a-zA-z0-0]*[/(][a-zA-z0-9]*[/)]$
```

but I get a syntax error saying unrelated token near ( . I cant figure out what i'm doing wrong. any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are a couple of mistakes. Here is what should work:

```
grep '^def [_a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9 ]*[\(][a-zA-Z0-9 ][a-zA-Z0-9 ]*[\)]$'
```

- I replaced your /- by underscore at the beginning of the regular expression
- I adjusted the backslash parenthesis
- I added some spaces in the classes in case it is needed
- I added a '[a-zA-Z0-9]' after the opening parenthesis to guaranty at least one letter between parenthesis. You can remove it if you want to allow empty text in parenthesis

Answer (score 1):

I think you want backslashes instead of forward slashes.